# Paperclip-ffmpeg not working on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg

Paperclip-ffmpeg works fine locally but on heroku it gives an error

```
[paperclip] [ffmpeg] avprobe "/tmp/8ca70bd5d70be60ba3060db50d50706220151231-3-1woqbc4.mp4" 2>&1
Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError (Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError):
```

Is FFMPEG install separetly on heroku?

My Gemfile

```
gem "cocaine"
gem 'paperclip-ffmpeg'
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'
```

Comment: which cocaine version you are using? if you don't have cocaine in your gemfile, please add before paperclip gem `gem "cocaine", "0.3.2"` and do `bundle install` and push on heroku.

Comment: I define gem "cocaine" in Gemfile

Comment: I update my question

Comment: you need this https://github.com/dzello/ffmpeg-heroku/

Comment: https://github.com/bcoe/thumbd/wiki/Running-Thumbd-on-Heroku

Comment: Can you explain what is this :O

Comment: To get video thumbnailing working on Heroku, you need to use custom buildpack to have an external ffmpeg binary. this link will show you how to install that https://github.com/bcoe/thumbd/wiki/Running-Thumbd-on-Heroku

Comment: Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

Comment: Thankuuuuu :) ... If you cant mind you can write this as answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get video thumbnailing working on Heroku, you need to use custom buildpack to have an external ffmpeg binary. This [link](http://github.com/bcoe/thumbd/wiki/Running-Thumbd-on-Heroku) will show you how to install that

If you get error like `Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app` after doing steps in first link.

This [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) will help you.